# Centering Text in Cell

Tags: tables, arrays

I am really confused as to why there is no centering on the second table. Two of the columns have shifted to the left. Why is the 2nd table no longer centered like the first table is?

Why does the second table need to use `\arraybackslash` but the first table does not?

A lot of the corrections I'm making to a document are switching around columns. I am trying my best to compare both tables and then move things around, but something always goes wrong or something is added to the second table that wasn't in the first.

So confused!

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow, array}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{bm}

\geometry{tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\fancyhead{}
\lhead{}
\chead{\fontsize{7}{12} \selectfont \textbf{Remarks on Notation, Size, and Shape of the Operating Matricies and Row and Column Vectors in ROSE} \\ \fontsize{6}{9} \selectfont Carl Ledbetter 3 June 2019}
\rhead{}

\title {Remarks on Notation, Size, and Shape of the Operating Matricies and Row and Column Vectors in ROSE}
\author{Carl Ledbetter}
\date{3 June 2019}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\[
\begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
 \hline
0 & \hat{0}_n  & \hat{0}_{(m+1)} \\
 \hline
d & \hat c  &  \\
\cdashline{1-2}
 & &  \\
\bar{b} & A & \\
 &  &   \multirow{-4.2}{*}{\centering ${I}_{(m+1)}$}   \\                       
\hline
 \end{array}
\]


\[
\begin{array}{|c|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering\arraybackslash\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|}
 \hline
\hat{0}_{(m+1)} & \hat{0}_n  & 0 \\
\hline
& \hat c & d \\
\cdashline{2-3}
& & \\
\multirow{-4.2}{*}{\centering ${I}_{(m+1)}$} & & \\
& A & \bar{b} \\
\hline
 \end{array}
\]

\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|p{2in}|}
    ...
    ...
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The factors the camera solver depends on to evaluate the rules.}
    \label{table:factors}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Erika, could you please remove non-issue related content from your MWE? Are you trying to insert your data as a equation through `\[ ... \]` or through a `table`/`tabular` environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your issues. When you ask about `centering`, there is the vertical and horizontal alignments.

First, there are three examples of basics uses of `multicolumn` and `multirow` inside the `tabular` environment.

In the sequence, there are two small editions of your code change the cells where the data is placed.

About `\arraybackslash`, read the following links:
[How to alter the alignment of tabular cells](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-tabcellalign) and 
[TeXblog -- Professional and clean tables with LaTeX](https://texblog.org/2017/02/06/proper-tables-with-latex/).

Please, note I didn't use more packages than necessary to reproduce your questions and I wrote only some auxiliary texts to enable a simple visualization.

The MWE follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

Example 1

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
            A          & B &         C          \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{D} & E &         F          \\
     \cdashline{2-3}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{G} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

Example 2

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
            A          &         B          &         C          \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{D} & \multirow{2}{*}{E} & \multirow{2}{*}{F} \\
                       &                    &                    \\
                       &                    &                    \\
     \cdashline{2-3}   & \multirow{2}{*}{G} & \multirow{2}{*}{H} \\
                       &                    &                    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

Example 3

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    A          &         B          &         C          \\
    \hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{D} & \multirow{2}{*}{E} & \multirow{2}{*}{F} \\
    &                    &                    \\
    &                    &                    \\
    \cdashline{2-3}   & \multirow{2}{*}{G} & \multirow{2}{*}{H} \\
    &                    &                    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

Replacing multirows and no negative input of the first option

\[
\begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
    \hline
    0               & \hat{0}_n & \hat{0}_{(m+1)}                           \\
    \hline
    d               & \hat c    & \multirow{4}{*}{\centering ${I}_{(m+1)}$} \\
    \cdashline{1-2} &           &                                           \\
    \bar{b}         & A         &                                           \\
                    &           &                                           \\
    \hline
\end{array}
\]

Replacing multirows and no negative input of the second option

\[
\begin{array}{|c|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering\arraybackslash\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|}
    \hline
                         \hat{0}_{(m+1)}                      & \hat{0}_n          & 0                          \\
    \hline
                                                              & \hat c             & d                          \\
    \cdashline{2-3} \multirow{4}{*}{\centering ${I}_{(m+1)}$} &                    &                            \\
                                                              & \multirow{3}{*}{A} & \multirow{3}{*}{$\bar{b}$} \\
                                                              &                    &                            \\
                                                              &                    &                            \\
    \hline
\end{array}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: A little tip I remembered: Avoid using extra empty cells. Check the [multirow Package documentation](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf) for some examples.